# Design - Sub-classes with similar implementations

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I'll try word this as succinctly as possible.

I currently have an object called a `StoresAdaptor` which inherits from a base class `ERPAdaptor`, that takes a `Stores` object and pushes it into a 3rd party ERP system via an adaptor design pattern.

Now, there are multiple types of these `Stores` movements. Each has their own implementation, but the creation is nigh on identical. The issue arises from the fact that this `Stores` object has the "To" location, and the `Line` object has the "From" location - however, when making a `Movement`, we need to know both the "To" and "From".

```
public class StoresAdaptor : ERPAdaptor
{
    protected Stores storesRequest
    {
        get { return (Stores) this.GenericObject; }
    }
    public StoresAdaptor(Data_Controller DCO, GenericObject storesRequest, ERPConnection conn)
        : base(DCO, storesRequest, conn)
    { }
    private class ReturnMiscMaterialAdaptor
    {
        //This here feels wrong...
        private StoresAdaptor _storesAdaptor;
        private Stores.Line _storesLine;

        public ReturnMiscMaterialAdaptor(StoresAdaptor storesAdaptorRef, Stores.Line storesLine)
        {
            _storesAdaptor= storesAdaptorRef;
            _storesLine= storesLine;
        }
     // task to bay
        public Update()
        {
            ERPSystem.ToLocation = _storesAdaptor.storesRequest.ToLocation;
            ERPSystem.FromLocation = _storesLine.FromLocation;
            //Return specific functionality
        }
    }
    private class IssueMiscMaterialAdaptor
    {
        //As well as here... there has to be a better way to do this...
        private StoresAdaptor _storesAdaptor;
        private Stores.Line _storesLine;

        public IssueMiscMaterialAdaptor(StoresAdaptor storesAdaptorRef, Stores.Line storesLine)
        {
            _storesAdaptor= storesAdaptorRef;
            _storesLine= storesLine;
        }
        public Update()
        {
            ERPSystem.ToLocation = _storesAdaptor.storesRequest.ToLocation;
            ERPSystem.FromLocation = _storesLine.FromLocation;
            //Issue specific functionality
        }
        // bay to task
    }
```

In essence, we need to keep the header object (`Stores`) exposed to all the sub-classes, whilst passing in the line (`Line`) to the separate sub-classes to be actioned appropriately.

What I've done so far is passed in a reference to the object in the sub-class constructor, but I find I'm repeating the exact same fields and ctor declaration (changing the name to match of course) which after the 3rd time of hitting "Paste" made me stop, and take a step back and realise I'm doing something wrong.

I've also considered making these `'sub-classes' : StoresAdaptor` but the base StoresAdaptor inherits from an abstract class with no parameterless constructor - and as such I would need to duplicate the constructor of the base class over and over.

Can anyone suggest which pattern would work best in this scenario? I will keep working on it but if I feel something is wrong with the pattern, there must be something VERY wrong with the design.

Comment: Please do let me know why the down-vote, rather than just down voting and leaving. I cannot learn if I am not given an opportunity to do so. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ReturnMiscMaterialAdaptor` and `IssueMiscMaterialAdaptor` appear to be inner classes. Is that right? Instead, make these subclasses to an `abstract class StoresAdaptor`.  `abstract` classes allow for inherited implementation, including constructors. Either or both of `ERPAdaptor` and `StoresAdaptor` could be `abstract` - I don't know enough about the design to be more specific.

---

Given the above you should not need to pass `Stores.Lines` parameter

---

`Stores.Line` appears to be a component inside of `Stores` so in `Stores` wrap that:

```
class Stores {
   public string FromLocation { get { return this.Line.FromLocation; }} 
}
```

---

Alternatively, but not preferred, you can wrap `Store` properties in the adapter class. Note, this is probably moot if inheritance, as suggested, is used.

BEFORE:

```
public Update()
    {
        ERPSystem.ToLocation = _storesAdaptor.storesRequest.ToLocation;
        ERPSystem.FromLocation = _storesLine.FromLocation;
        //Return specific functionality
    }
```

AFTER:

```
public ReturnMiscMaterialAdaptor(StoresAdaptor storesAdaptorRef, Stores.Line storesLine)
    {
        _storesAdaptor= storesAdaptorRef;
        _storesLine= storesLine;
        this.ToLocation = _storesAdaptor.storesRequest.ToLocation;
        this.FromLocation = _storesLine.FromLocation;
    }    
public Update()
    {
        ERPSystem.ToLocation = this.ToLocation;
        ERPSystem.FromLocation = this.FromLocation;
        //Return specific functionality
    }
```

---

In general, I'm saying apply the least knowledge principle in the adaptee and adaptor classes.

---

I disagree with the notion stated in another answer that the adapter classes could be static. How can you expose an API for a stateful object and guarantee its consistency? What happens when the client needs a second adapted object?

---

P.S. adaptor is misspelled, should be adapter.

Comment: I like this response. The design is simple yet perfect for our requirements. And it removes the need for unnecessarily complicated code! As for the spelling of Adaptor/Adapter - I am more familiar with the latter also, but for whatever reason, we've chosen to go with the former spelling.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is easily solved once you realize that one does not need a `StoresAdaptor` and a `Stores.Line` in order to build a `ReturnMiscMaterialAdaptor` or a `IssueMiscMaterialAdaptor`, nor the class needs to keep them in the internal state in order to function. Base on your code, they seem not needed until the `Update` method is called, so they should be parameters of that call, instead.

In fact, it almost looks like the `Adaptor` classes are good candidates for `static` classes -- of course not currently possible because they are subclasses of `ERPAdaptor`.

A possible alternative solution:

```
private class IssueMiscMaterialAdaptor
{
    public IssueMiscMaterialAdaptor() { }

    public Update(StoresAdaptor storesAdaptorRef, Stores.Line storesLine)
    {
        var _storesAdaptor= storesAdaptorRef;
        var _storesLine= storesLine;
        ERPSystem.ToLocation = _storesAdaptor.storesRequest.ToLocation;
        ERPSystem.FromLocation = _storesLine.FromLocation;
        //Issue specific functionality
    }
    // bay to task
}
```

or even

```
private class IssueMiscMaterialAdaptor
{
    public IssueMiscMaterialAdaptor() { }

    public Update(Location toLocation, Location fromLocation)
    {
        ERPSystem.ToLocation = toLocation;
        ERPSystem.FromLocation = fromLocation;
        //Issue specific functionality
    }
    // bay to task
}
```

Comment: I like this response also! I am partial to the static classes idea, but the alternatives provided are great ideas - both to provide the required fields or the objects into the method themselves. If I could mark this as an answer also, I would as it does answer the question. As it is said, "there are many ways to skin a cat" - and this is most definitely a good way to do so!